# Pass 1d or 2d vector to constructor of same class

Tags: c++, vector

I'm about to create class, handling 2d vector of doubles. I want to pass either vector of vectors, or simple vector of doubles (in case, that second dimension is 1 element wide) to constructor. Also, it's for modal dialog for editing underlying data, so, i'm passing vector by reference.

Some code for reference of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
class TableEditDialog {
    using Table2d = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

public:
    TableEditDialog(Table2d & data) : m_data( data ) {}
    TableEditDialog(std::vector<double> & data); // ?

private:
    Table2d& m_data;
};
```

In case of passing simple vector of doubles with N elements, I need `m_data` to be either `vector<vector<double>>` , which contains N vectors of one element, or one vector of N elements.

I've tried to utilize delegating constructors with no success.
Also I've tried to create new temporary 2d vector in second constructor, but it breaks the idea of passing by reference to edit underlying data.

Comment: What is a 1d vector but a 2d vector where one of the dimensions is 1?

Comment: @user4581301 , for example: caller contains `vector<double> = {1, 2, 3}`, but when this data is passed to my class, I want it to be interpreted either as `vector<vector<double>> = {{1, 2, 3}}` or `vector<vector<double>> = {{1}, {2}, {3}}`

Answer (score 2):

Make `TableEditDialog` a class template so the type can be specified at construction.

```c++
template<class T>
class TableEditDialog {
public:
  TableEditDialog(T& data) : m_data( data ) {}
private:
  T& m_data;
};
```

You can also make a function to help with type deduction:

```c++
template<class T>
TableEditDialog<T> make_table_edit_dialog(T& data) {
  return data;
}
```

Then you can do:

```c++
std::vector<double> d1d;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> d2d;

auto ted1 = make_table_edit_dialog(d1d);
auto ted2 = make_table_edit_dialog(d2d);
```

EDIT:

If you would like to convert the 1D array case to a 2D array, you can overload the constructor for a 1D vector and initialize `m_data` by copying the vector into it:

```c++
class TableEditDialog {
  using Array1d = std::vector<double>;
  using Array2d = std::vector<Array1d>;
public:
  TableEditDialog(Array2d& data) : m_data( data ) {}
  TableEditDialog(Array1d& data) : m_data(1, data) {}
private:
  Array2d m_data;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for great option. But then another problem comes in. We need different code base to handle 1d type and 2d type internally, when we, for example, iterating over elements. Is there a way to somehow convert 1d case to 2d case during construction, so, that all other code base within that class will remain designed for 2d vector?

Comment: @DenisGolovkin It might be easier to make a special overload for the 2d array case, flatten the array and treat it as a 1 dimension array. You can access the indices using a special trick: For a 2D array of size `width x height`, put all the elements into a 1D array of size `width x height` and access the elements as a 1D array using `array[width * row + col]`.

Comment: @DenisGolovkin But if you want to convert a 1D array to a 2D array, that can also be done. I'll update in a second.

Comment: Thank you! That's a great improvement. Now this class can access and visualize the data correctly in both 1d and 2d cases. The only thing, I must figure out is how to modify the underlying `data`, since `m_data` is not more a reference, but a copy.

Comment: @DenisGolovkin You can change the data structure to `vector<reference_wrapper<vector<double>>>` so that you essentially hold references to the underlying data. `std::reference_wrapper` can be found in `<functional>`. If I think of something better than that I'll let you know.

Comment: @DenisGolovkin Sorry. I meant use `shared_ptr` as in `vector<shared_ptr<vector<double>>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert 1d vector to 2d vector storing references of element. The only drawback of such solution is, that you are not allowed to play with this 1d vector until you finished editing, elsewhere things may break.

Here are example:

```
TableEditDialog(std::vector<double> & data) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double>>> result(data.size());
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), result.begin(), [](double& d) {return {{d}};});
}
```

Though, I didn't test this, and may be you need to use `{{std::forward(d)}}` in lambda.

The only problem left you have different definition of m_data, but same access semantics, so you either need to use templated code to access it or use std::variant.